# How to write wizard function to print a qweb report?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have following challenge .I have created on module named as **sales_invoice** .I have created one report for **account.invoice**  object.

mom_report.xml file contains

```
    <openerp>
        <data>
         <report
                id="action_report_mom"
                string="MoM"
                model="account.invoice"
                report_type="qweb-pdf"
                name="sales_invoice.report_mom"
                file="sales_invoice.report_mom"
            /></data></openerp>
```

mom_view.xml I have following code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <openerp>
        <data>
             <act_window name="Pass-01 Invoice"
                res_model="prints.wizard"
                src_model="account.invoice"
                view_mode="form"
                view_type="form"
                multi="False"
                target="new"
                key2="client_print_multi"
                id="action_pass_id"/>
              </data>
           </openerp>
```

**sales_invoice/views**  I have following template in the name of **report_mom.xml**
      
        
        
            
           
                
            Report is in between this

I have created wizard sales_invoice/wizard folder has following files
**print_invoice.py**

```
    class prints_wizard(osv.osv_memory):

        _name="prints.wizard"


        _columns={


            'selection_item':fields.selection([('first', 'First Stage Dealer'), ('secon', 'Second Stage Dealer')],'Stage'),
        }


        def print_report(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
            datas = {}
            if context is None:
                context = {}
            datas['ids'] = context.get('active_ids', [])
            datas['model'] = context.get('active_model', 'ir.ui.menu')      
            return self.pool['report'].get_action(cr, uid, [], 'sales_invoice.report_mom', data=datas, context=context)
```

**print_invoice_view.xml** file has following code

```
<openerp>
            <data>
                 <record id="view_print_order" model="ir.ui.view">
                  <field name="name">prints.wizard</field>
                  <field name="model">prints.wizard</field>
                  <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <form string="Print The Copy of " >
                        <group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="selection_item" />

                            </group>
                        </group>
                        <footer>
                            <button name="print_report" context="{'open_purchase': True}" string="Print" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                            <!-- <button name="create_supplier" string="Dummy invoice" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/> -->
                        </footer>
                    </form>
                  </field>
                </record>
                <record id="action_pass1_update_wizard" model="ir.actions.act_window">
                    <field name="name">Pass-01 Invoice</field>
                    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
                    <field name="res_model">prints.wizard</field>

                    <field name="view_type">form</field>
                    <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
                    <field name="target">new</field>

                </record>
               </data>
        </openerp>
```

report template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<template id="report_mom">
    <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
   <div class="header">
        <div class="clearfix"><br /></div>
all code here
</div>
</t>

</template>
</data>
</openerp>
```

It is working fine .I mean in print option i am getting print of th report .I have one task like .I have created wizard its coming fine.In that wizard i have one selection field .When he clicks **Pass-01 Invoice** from print it will open wizard there I will select some stages like if i select **First Stage Dealer** and click on print option.It has to do following action
        1)It have to print that report 
        2)In that report header has to be in there name of ***First Stage Dealer***
I am getting difficult to write function for that print button

Comment: one thing is still missing....the report template please paste it